# Не отображает теги django-taggit

Tags: python, django

Подключил библиотеку `django-taggit`, изменил все как надо, по книжке Дронова, но как всегда ничего не работает: теги не сохраняются в базе данных. В документации, вычитал вот эту фразу:

> If, when saving a form, you use the commit=False option you’ll need to
>   call save_m2m() on the form after you save the object, just as you
>   would for a form with normal many to many fields on it.

Отлично, сделал согласно документации, внес `save_m2m()` во view, все равно теги не сохраняются. То есть при занесении нового объекта в форме строчка Tags появляется, я ее заполняю, но в базе эти данные не сохранятся почему то.

Через Shell проверяю внесенную запись - тегов НЕТ, `{'taggit.TaggedItem': 0, ...}`

Все миграции базы данных давно успешно сделаны.

Как сохранить теги в базе данных?

Модель:

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
...
class Cities(models.Model):
    country=models.ForeignKey(Countries, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True, verbose_name='Теги')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'ГОРОДА'  
    def __str__(self):
        return self.city_name
```

Формы:

```
class CitiesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cities
        fields = ['city_name']
        labels = {'city_name': 'Type name of city'}
    tags=TagField(label='Tags')
```

Представление:

```
def new_city(request, countries_id):
    country=Countries.objects.get(id=countries_id)
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form=CitiesForm()
    else:
        form=CitiesForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_city=form.save(commit=False)
            new_city.country=country
            new_city.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('countries:cities', args=[country.id]))
    context={'country': country, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'countries/new_city.html', context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, господа, после нескольких часов танцов с бубном найдено решение! Чтобы принудительно сохранить теги в базе нужно на уровне функций представлений использовать цикл for для form.cleaned_data['tags'] и привязку тегов к объекту через код obj.tags.add(). На примере моей функции-представления, которая показана выше, рабочий код такой (может он и говнокод, но он РАБОТАЕТ, а лучше решения за сутки никто не смог предложить):

```
@login_required
def new_city(request, countries_id):
    country=Countries.objects.get(id=countries_id)
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form=CitiesForm()
    else:
        form=CitiesForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_city=form.save(commit=False)
            new_city.country=country
            new_city.save()
            for tag in form.cleaned_data['tags']:
                new_city.tags.add(tag)
        ....
```

Потом вставляем в шаблон подобный код, как учил Дронов, и прекрасно все работает - теги сохраняются в базе через отправленную форму, прекрасно отображаются, через запятую, фильтруются, все отлично, господа!

```
{% with names=city.tags.names %}
  {% if names.count > 0 %}
     Tags: {% for name in names %}{% if not forloop.first %}, {% endif %} <a href="..."> {{ name }} </a> {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```